# WARNING **: Sink input info callback : SINK INPUT INFO IS NULL or our user_data is not what we think it should be

Tags: sound, syslog

could someone please explain to me what this means? It appeared in my syslog after what I can only describe as an "analogy sounding pig noise" came over my speakers. I recently installed ubuntu 16.04 then installed Lubuntu-desktop on top of it. Please let me know if there is any other relevant information that I should share.

```
Dec 24 05:57:59 <USER> com.canonical.indicator.sound-gtk2[1672]: ** (process:2174): WARNING **: Sink input info callback : SINK INPUT INFO IS NULL or our user_data is not what we think it should be
```

I can't seem to find any information on this particular warning.